# Angular2 with Spring Boot and Spring Security

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

First of all, I already check the question at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106799/angular2-spring-boot-security) and I try his solution but at the end, I still have the same issue.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:8080/login`.
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> Origin `http://localhost:3000` is therefore not allowed access.
> The response had HTTP status code 403.

However, I put an `access-control` everywhere so I don't understand why it's like this.

My code looks like this (I hope I will put enough for you):

In Angular, my `login.service.ts`:

```js
check(name: string, password: string): boolean {
     let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers,withCredentials:true});

    if(this.http.post(this.baseUrl, 
        `username=${name}&password=${password}`,
        {headers:headers})
        .toPromise().then(response=> {
          return {}
        }))
        return true;    

        return false;
  }
```

I also want to return a boolean if the authentication succeed but I don't really know how to know if it works, so I do it like that for now (and it's always true).

Then, in Java, I have this code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

then for the security, I got this :

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    
    @Autowired
    private RESTLoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private RestLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //deactivate CSRF and use custom impl for CORS
        httpSecurity
                .cors.and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
        //authorize, authenticate rest
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .usernameParameter("username")
                    .passwordParameter("password")
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutSuccessHandler(this.logoutSuccessHandler)
                    .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("rano").password("1234").roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8080","http://localhost:3000"));
        
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("PUT","DELETE","POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

In my LoginSuccessHandler :

```
@Component
public class RESTLoginSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            org.springframework.security.core.Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

        SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);

        if (savedRequest == null) {
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
            return;
        }

        String targetUrlParam = getTargetUrlParameter();
        if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
                || (targetUrlParam != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParam)))) {
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
            clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
            return;
        }

        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    public void setRequestCache(RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
    }
}
```

So, any idea on what is the problem? Or on how to make an Angular2 app with Spring Boot and Spring Security? Because everything works between Spring Boot and Angular except when I add the security.

Comment: I removed the `.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);` but the `corsConfigurationSource`, what I wrote in my question is what I wrote in my code. I completly did it wrong?

Comment: this time I don't have any Cors message, but a new error :
 `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

Comment: I get what you was saying about the `corsConfigurationSource` and yes, it's in my class in my code. However, for the Spring Security log, the Debug is enabled but I see nothing in the Java side, and in the Angular side I still see the 403 error.
But, when I delete `.addFilter...` I have no longer this error but the problem with Unexpected token.

Comment: I add in my question my `loginSuccessHandler`, but I also decided to follow a course on a webapp with Angular2 and Java Spring. I hope like that I will see what I did wrong. Maybe it's something I did somewhere else again. If just with my `loginSuccesshandler` you can see what I did wrong, it will be perfect, otherwise I will do the course and check my problem at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your configure method

```
.cors().and()
```

Comment: I did it and he's looking for 'org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter' and my CorsFilter is in 'org.cedric.filters.CorsFilter'.

So, the error looks like that : 
      Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Comment: Read http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html

Comment: I add this code in my question, because in comment it's ugly to read.

And still the same issue, I misunderstand something?

Comment: I erased what I wrote in my WebConfig class, and delete my custom CorsFilter, then add .cors in my configure method and wrote the corsConfigurationSource method like in my question. The java side run but I still get the allow-access error. I forgot to erase something ? I read the other answer you gave me and it's still not working.

Comment: Thank you, worked in my case! With no need to configure cors separately.